# How can I fix the size of header logo in asp .net (without cropping) to zoom out page?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, zooming

edit: Here is my screenshot below:
[Normal view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Fpz5.png)
[Zoom out view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tr9Un.png)

I always research on stackoverflow during my work but this is my first question.
when i zoom in there is no cropping problem but zooming out crops the header logo. How can i fix this? Thanks a lot. Here is my code below:

```
/* background */
.content
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background: url(Styles/light.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

/* header logo */
.header 
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 227px;
    background: url(images/header.png) no-repeat center top;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
        <div id="loading" class="loading" align="center">
            Loading. Please wait.<br />
        </div>
        <form runat="server">
        <div class="page">
            <div class="main">
                <div class="header">
                    <div class="HeaderText" style="font-size: 60px; color: #014464;">
                        <div class="marka" style="margin: auto; width: 921px; height: 143px">
                            <div class="logo">
                                <h1>
                                    <a href="/MainPage.aspx">
                                    </a>
                                </h1>
                            </div>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <br />
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <br />
                            <br />

                            <div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: right; position:static; width:auto;">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
</body>
```

Comment: please add your html code too..

Comment: What do you expect/want to happen when you zoom out?

Comment: This is a HTML/CSS question. Nothing to do with ASP.NET or Razor directly, it would seem (they are just used to create the HTML which will be the subject of the question). Please remove irrelevant tags. And it's almost certainly impossible to answer the question without seeing the related HTML, and ideally an example of what it should look like when "zoomed out" (to what %, incidentally?).

Comment: @Ken Syme Items are getting mixed up each other. (I mean the tabs that include menu items). Sorry for not sharing the tabs, its kind of privacy policy in our company that i work for.

Comment: @Vishnu Sorry i have forgotten it, im gonna update question.

Comment: @HandeAydemir your HTML code doesn't actually contain any content, and I'm still not sure what it is you want to happen when you zoom out - is it just to make the background get smaller/stretched? The reason it is clipping is the keyword `background-size: cover` - it tries to maintain the width of the page, but will also keep the aspect ratio and so it will get taller as well. Cover means it will make sure to cover the entire background area with the image, even if the image gets clipped. Try using `background-size: contain` and see if that is what you want.